# Woodwing: how to trigger the ModalViewController using custom web/html embedded content

Tags: iphone, ipad, adobe-indesign

Using Woodwing, we have a page that has custom html in it, using the custom web widget.

That widget has an anchor tag, that when tapped, opens a page in safari.

However, if we create the same page using the HTML widget, and a link overlay, that triggers a ModalView to display.

I'm assuming this has something to do with WoodWing's (un)documented protocols for the anchor tags, that are captured by the WoodWing shell application and used to trigger the "ModalView" display. Since everything in Woodwing generates an XML that is parsed when the app is loaded, and I've done numerous applications, this seems reasonable. However, there is very little technical documentation.

My question is: does anyone know any documentation on those protocols, or a way I can use custom-html to trigger the ModalView? I've tried replacing "http" with "ww" but no dice. It's possible it's javascript but I'm suspecting protocols...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default HTML widget implementation doesn't support this out of the box. There are two ways that you can do to achieve this;

- Implement what they call a 'custom object'. They documented this feature, if you have access to their documentation this should be relatively easy to figure out. It allows you to write native objects and inject them into both the .ofip format and the application.
- Implement a modal dialog within the widget (in HTML). This is less convenient but possible to do (if you have a fullscreen widget).

Comment: That makes sense... but I'd rather hook into the modal view that's supported by the anchor tag's protocol (http or ww or what-not). Besides trial-and-error, is there anything in the documentation or support regarding how to trigger the Modal from opening using an anchor tag?

Comment: I'm afraid there is absolutely no way to do that, documented or undocumented.

Comment: I find your lack of faith disturbing. Their documentation, the way they built their system, everything they've done point to a undocumented method to do this. The modal view triggers on their "drag-and-drop" anchor click trigger widget. The auto-generated code for this definitely creates the html... which makes think the answer is in the indesign plugin -> generated codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The UIWebViewDelegate defines the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method that your view controller can implement. In this implementation, your code shoudl decide if it wants to handle the request (user click) or let the UIWebView handle it normally.

For displaying a modal as a result of a click, this method would display the modal and return `NO`.

Comment: We don't have access to the source / iOS code in Woodwing, only the InDesign and html-injected code. I'm looking for insight into the Woodwing source to figure out how to create a url or javascript call that will trigger the "Woodwing" modal action to occur. If you examine their documentation (which is both thorough and semi-obtuse) you'll see they use ww://someAction or ww://someView to do certain custom actions (i.e. they've built in that UIWebViewDelegate handler). But what request should I make?

Answer (score 0):

Create the specific URL for open as you mention in your comment(ww://string.string).
Then in UIWebView Delegate method (webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:) get the redirect URL. If redirect URL is equal to you mention before then perform your action.

Let me know if this answer help you.

Thanks,

Comment: Using WoodWing you don't have access to their UIWebView Delegate source code. They are already implementing it. What I need to know is WHAT is the protocol definition?